# How to force a Debian Stretch ethernet to 10MBit?

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager

I have an headless embedded board with ARM and Stretch, and the ethernet does not work correctly at 100Mbit, but works correctly at 10Mbit.

I'd like to force 10Mbit, but I need to do this before dhclient starts, otherwise I don't get an IP address.

So far I did this in `rc.local`:

```
echo SETTING eth0 to 10Mbit
/sbin/ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex half autoneg off 
if [ -n "`pgrep dhclient`" ] then
   dhclient -r
   dhclient
fi
```

However, this leaves me with 2 dhclient instances, which I'm not sure is the right way:

```
~ ps auxf | grep dhc
root       917  0.0  1.6   6692  1972 ?        Ss   Jul31   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -4 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -l
root     16783  0.0  1.4   4336  1772 pts/1    S+   07:07   0:00          \_ grep dhc
root      1571  0.0  1.5   6692  1892 ?        Ss   Jul31   0:00 dhclient
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using NetworkManager, run the following command, replacing `<connection_name>` with the actual name of your NetworkManager connection configuration:

```
nmcli connection modify <connection_name> 802-3-ethernet.speed 10 802-3-ethernet.duplex half 802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate no
```

If you're not using NetworkManager, you probably already have `iface eth0 inet dhcp` in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Place your `ethtool` command after it in a `pre-up` option:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    pre-up /sbin/ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex half autoneg off
```

The above assumes a normal Debian Stretch. Raspbian may be different here.